# Is it possible to set Apache Basic Authentication to lock a directory, except for one file?

Tags: authentication, apache2

I'm working on an upcoming project, but the team needs to access it online. I've setup (for now) Basic Authentication using:

```
    <Directory /var/www/html>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Staging"
            AuthUserFile /etc/passwd
            Require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

But, I need one file to be publically accessible (a 3rd party service needs to ping it, but can't handle Basic Authentication. Is it possible to "turn off" authentication for a specific file ("specific-file.php")?

I was looking into:

```
    <Files "/var/www/html/specific-file.php">
            ### SOMETHING
    </Files>
```

but it is not clear to me how to disable the protection.

Thanks!

Comment: This serverfault answer worked for me: http://serverfault.com/questions/151240/how-to-use-basic-auth-for-single-file-in-otherwise-forbidden-apache-directory

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
Allow from all
Satisfy any
```

Answer (score -1):

what happens when you use following?

```
<Files "/var/www/html/specific-file.php">
        Order Deny, Allow
        Allow from all
        AuthType none
        Satisfy Any 
</Files>
```

or a try a combination of above.

Comment: No joy. Seems not to work. I also tried to use Location with the same directives, but that actually seemed toc completely disable security.

Comment: hmm... did you try putting `Satisfy Any` before `Allow from all` as well? Try using `AuthType none` as well!

Comment: Still no joy. Just completely turns off Authorization at all.